# c# How to access the items from a parent class combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, combobox, datasource

I have, among other components within the 'dialog' form, this combobox. I want to declare that its datasource or its item list to be the same as a previous combobox I created in the design, and to which I loaded its data from a file. How I do that?

```
public partial class CardBuilder : Form
{
    public CardBuilder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        private static class A
        {
            private static string ShowDialog(string T, string C, int AT)
            {
                int WX = system.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width,
                    WY = system.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height;
                string AbilityResult = "";

                Form dialog = new Form
                {
                    Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Garamond", 15,
                    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                    System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ((byte)(0))),
                    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D,
                    Text = C,
                    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                    Location = new Point(WY - WY / 4, (WX - 350) / 2),
                    AutoSize = false,
                    SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Hide,
                    Owner = CardBuilder.ActiveForm,
                    ShowIcon = false,
                    ControlBox = false,
                    TopMost = true,
                    Width = 350,
                    Height = 140
                };
                ComboBox CT = new ComboBox()
                {
                    DataSource = ??
                    Sorted = true
                };
                return Result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: By "same as a previous combobox I created in the design", what do you mean? What is the previous comboxes code in this context?

Comment: The main class has one combobox which was auto-created by the VS, and to which I loaded its items from a file. I pretend to copy the contents of those items into the CT combobox

Comment: Then you would just reference that combobox and set `CT.DataSource = this.comboBox1.DataSource;`. You just need to get the existing comboboxes name property and reference it by that name.

Comment: I tried that and I get the CS0120 error (object reference required for non-static field)

Comment: I solved it. It works the same as copying a combobox range, by using the AddRange() method, like this:    CT.Items.AddRange(comboBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray());

Comment: That's because you are calling it from a static class. You can pass in the reference from the Form by changing it to: `private static string ShowDialog(string T, string C, int AT, ComboBox refCB)` then using it like that to set the `DataSource`

Comment: You would have ran into the same issue by using AddRange, so you must have also passed in a reference or made the method non-static or something.

Comment: Corylulu you're right. I first thought my fix was working, because in the meantime I tried using the main form as base and removed the static. But then it couldn't be called from outside the class. I tried your suggestions and it works just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution so you can mark it as answered :)

```
    private static class A
    {
        private static string ShowDialog(string T, string C, int AT, ComboBox copyFrom)
        {
            int WX = system.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width,
                WY = system.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height;
            string AbilityResult = "";

            Form dialog = new Form
            {
                Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Garamond", 15,
                System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ((byte)(0))),
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D,
                Text = C,
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                Location = new Point(WY - WY / 4, (WX - 350) / 2),
                AutoSize = false,
                SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Hide,
                Owner = CardBuilder.ActiveForm,
                ShowIcon = false,
                ControlBox = false,
                TopMost = true,
                Width = 350,
                Height = 140
            };
            ComboBox CT = new ComboBox()
            {
                DataSource = copyFrom.DataSource,
                Sorted = true
            };
            return Result;
        }
    }
```